# Rails has_many :through --> Should I keep a primary key column?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, database-design, primary-key, has-many-through

I have 'author' and 'book' tables, joined in a has_many :through table 'author_book'

As far as I can tell, there's no purpose to an :id primary key field on the 'author_book' table...but before I commit to that idea, I just wanted to confirm. So, is there any reason for keeping the 'id' column on a has_many :through table?

Thanks in advance...

Comment: You must make sure you add 2 indexes for these relations:

add_index table_name, [ :author_id, :book_id ]
add_index table_name, [ :book_id, :author_id ]

This makes sure you have the ability to go each way through the relation without needing table scans.  From the names of these tables in the example, you can also add a ':unique => true' to these to stop duplicates

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Keep it.  Later on youll find the unique identifier pay off in ways that aren't obvious initially.
Unlike other agile development principles, it's better to get data quality items like this addressed up front.

Comment: Sounds mysterious. Care to share the "ways that aren't obvious initially"? Possibly with practical examples.

Answer (score 3):

If you ever have something unique to the author-book relationship, you'll need the `id` to  set it in this table via an `AuthorBook` model.  It doesn't sound like a likely scenario in this case, and you can add it later if you need to.

Answer (score 3):

If it's `has_many through` that means that  `author_book` is a active record model, so please leave id for it. But if you'll use `has_and_belongs_to_many` connecting table doesn't need id http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Associations/ClassMethods/has_and_belongs_to_many